# GCC Stack overflow by negative number

Tags: c++, gcc, buffer, overflow, flash-memory

I'm getting a very strange error msg. A negative Flash overflow. How is this possible

I'm calling a debug function to print out error msgs on multiple occasions. This error logger function looks like this

```
BOOLEAN C_Wrapper_Write_to_File(
const char *const p_ch_Log_File_Name,
const char *const p_ch_log_msg,
const char *const p_ch_File,
const int i_line);
```

I'm calling this function at multiple occasions like this

```
C_Wrapper_Write_to_File("debug","a veeerrryyy lonnngggg error messssssagge", __FILE__,__LINE__);
```

**Result:** this one produces a flash overflow by **positive** 16 byte.

If I reduce the string length I'm getting a **negative** flash overflow

```
C_Wrapper_Write_to_File("debug","tiny", __FILE__,__LINE__);
```

```
../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../bin/3_zellen_2017.elf section `.data' will not fit in region `FLASH'
../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region `FLASH' overflowed by -24 bytes
```

Now i'm well aware that all const char[] Arrays are stored in the flash. So it makes perfectly sense to me, that when i shorten the Error the Flash usage decreases.

**Problem:**

> Section `'.data'` will not fit in region `'FLASH'`... Region `'FLASH'` overflowed by **-24 bytes**

How to fix the error message about a negative number?

Comment: **(1)** Why `const` is used? Doesn't that stop you from changing values (_eg:_ cannot change length of message)? For a constant pointer to a char, try as `char *const p_ch_log_msg` not as `const char *const p_ch_log_msg`. Also try that same setup for those other function parameters. **(2)** Why `char` instead of `std::String`? **(3)** What string/char specific length doesn't cause a buffer overflow or underflow here?

Comment: hey, (1)I do not need to modify the values therefore it's const. And in case of p_ch_File, i must not modify them because the Macro __FILE__ is used to pass this parameter.  Why would removing the fist const improve the situation? (3) char* are used becuase this is part of a c wrapper. The underlying architecture are indeed strings ;)

Comment: Hi after re-reading your message I've realized your `Flash` tag is actually about `Flash Memory`. It's possible to [use C++ inside Adobe Flash](https://adobe-flash.github.io/crossbridge/) and assumed too quick that was your problem (because `GCC`, `C_Wrapper` and `Flash` are things relating to Adobe Flash too).

Comment: PS: My assumption was removing the first const stops the char itself being a constant (and non-modifiable). You want an editable **char with a constant pointer**.